# Как разбить временной ряд xts, по 6 колонок в сутки? R

Tags: r

Недавно начал изучать R. Имеется датасет в формате xts c шагом в 4 часа:

`2017-01-02 03:00:00 0.00807072
2017-01-02 07:00:00 0.00806009
2017-01-02 11:00:00 0.00786399
2017-01-02 15:00:00 0.00809601
2017-01-02 19:00:00 0.00817887
2017-01-02 23:00:00 0.00822048
2017-01-03 03:00:00 0.00811701
2017-01-03 07:00:00 0.00835698
2017-01-03 11:00:00 0.00838292
2017-01-03 15:00:00 0.00916666
2017-01-03 19:00:00 0.00962500
2017-01-03 23:00:00 0.00928000`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу преобразовать его так, что бы у меня вышел временной ряд с 6 колонками в сутки? Вот так:

`2017-01-02 0.00807072 0.00806009 0.00786399 0.00809601 0.00817887 0.00822048 
2017-01-03 0.00811701 0.00835698 0.00838292 0.00916666 0.00962500 0.00928000`

Answer (score 0):

```
## ---- Загрузка пакетов ---

library(data.table)
library(xts)

## ---- Создание образца данных ----

x <- fread("
2017-01-02 03:00:00 0.00807072
2017-01-02 07:00:00 0.00806009
2017-01-02 11:00:00 0.00786399
2017-01-02 15:00:00 0.00809601
2017-01-02 19:00:00 0.00817887
2017-01-02 23:00:00 0.00822048
2017-01-03 03:00:00 0.00811701
2017-01-03 07:00:00 0.00835698
2017-01-03 11:00:00 0.00838292
2017-01-03 15:00:00 0.00916666
2017-01-03 19:00:00 0.00962500
2017-01-03 23:00:00 0.00928000
")

setnames(x, c("date", "time", "value"))

x[, date := paste(date, time)]
x[, date := as.POSIXct(date, tz = "GTM")]
x[, time := NULL]

xt <- as.xts(x)

rm(x)

## ---- Преобразование данных ----

d <- as.data.table(xt)
d[, date := as.Date(index)]
d[, time := paste0("hour_", format(index, "%H"))]
res <- dcast(d, date ~ time, value.var = "value")
res
#>          date    hour_03    hour_07    hour_11    hour_15    hour_19    hour_23
#> 1: 2017-01-02 0.00807072 0.00806009 0.00786399 0.00809601 0.00817887 0.00822048
#> 2: 2017-01-03 0.00811701 0.00835698 0.00838292 0.00916666 0.00962500 0.00928000
```